# Can't center webpage Footer and make it resize with window ratio

Tags: html, css

I have tried many codes and they have worked, but when i tried to make two *div* side by side for the footer, i couldn't then center it and I haven't been able to get it to work with the user window ratio ever since, even after trying codes from others i still couldn't manage to fix it.

The problem here is that i can't make what is inside the Footer centered, and yet still change acording to the user window ratio.

```css
/* Footer */

#sides{
    /*margin-left:750px;*/
}
#left{
    float:left;
    text-align: left;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.footer {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #99ffdd;
}


.footer-distributed{
    background-color: #2c292f;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font: bold 16px sans-serif;
    padding: 50px 50px 60px 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-left,
.footer-distributed .footer-center{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* Footer left */
.footer-distributed .footer-left{
    width: 14%;
}

/* Footer Center */
.footer-distributed .footer-center p{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p a{
    color:  #e0ac1c;
    text-decoration: none;;
}

@media (max-width: 880px) {

    .footer-distributed .footer-left,
    .footer-distributed .footer-center{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .footer-distributed .footer-center i{
        margin-left: 0;
    }

}
```

```html
<footer class="footer-distributed">
    <div class="footer-left">
        <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px" src="http://localhost/Window_Cleaner/pictures/paypal/paypal_support.png">
    </div>
    <div class="footer-center">
        <a class="contactme" href="http://localhost/Window_Cleaner/menu/contact.html">
            <h2>Contact me</h2>
        </a>
        <div>
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
            <p>+99 99999 999999</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
            <p><a href="mailto:example@hotmail.com">example@hotmail.com</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using absolute positioning on the left image.

```css
/* Footer */

#sides {
    /*margin-left:750px;*/
}

#left {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footer {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #99ffdd;
}

.footer-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.footer-distributed {
    background-color: #2c292f;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font: bold 16px sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer-distributed">
    <div class="footer-left">
        <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px" src="http://localhost/Window_Cleaner/pictures/paypal/paypal_support.png">
    </div>
    <div class="footer-center">
        <a class="contactme" href="http://localhost/Window_Cleaner/menu/contact.html">
            <h2>Contact me</h2>
        </a>
        <div>
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
            <p>+99 99999 999999</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
            <p><a href="mailto:example@hotmail.com">example@hotmail.com</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```